# How to open pop-up file using Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am trying to open a file in pop-up using angular 6 for my project but I am getting error.

I want to open **pdf** file or other file in pop-up window.

please kindly advice steps on how i could go about it, thanking you all in advance.

Comment: Add your code and the error to the question.

Comment: I want to open pdf file or other file in pop-up

Comment: What is that error?

Comment: I want to know the steps in Angular 6 on how to open pop-up file

Answer (score 0):

Angular material will help you. They have popup functionality.You can read some from docs [Angular Material PopUps/Dialogs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)
If somethings from docs, you cant understand, be free to ask me!

**EDIT**: If you need PDF Viewer you can use [PDF Viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer)
And insert this in Material Dialogs.

Comment: I want view the file in pop-up? how can i go about that.

Comment: I want to open PDF or other file in Pop-up

Comment: Do you have a some PDF Viewer?

Comment: Actually want to have plugin in angular 6 for this can you suggest me the name or some steps

Comment: I am using Angular 6 for my project.